# AnimatedSprite displays with wrong size

Tags: android, andengine

Sorry if this problem was asked before. I have searched around but I didn't find any thread about this, So I post the question here.

I am really new on Andengine. I am trying to load a Tiled Sprite and create an animation with it.
Here are my codes:

```
public void loadGameResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/player/");
    mSapoTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mActivity.getTextureManager(),256,178,TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    mPlayerDownITiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mPlayerTextureAtlas, mActivity.getAssets(), "player.png", 0,0,3,1);
    mPlayerTextureAtlas.load();

}
```

What I expect is that the player can do some actions like walking but I don't. Please see the attached screenshots to see the real result. I think that my codes split the original texture into 3 parts rather than just split 3 sprites at first row.

Please take a look and help me to fix this. Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
And here is how I create the animation:

```
AnimatedSprite player= new AnimatedSprite(100,100,40,40,mResourceManager.mPlayerDownITiledTextureRegion,mVertexBufferObjectManager);
player.animate(500);
player.setZIndex(100);
attachChild(sapo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that you want to animate the player in each direction properly. For that

According to library method

> BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(pBitmapTextureAtlas, pAssetManager, pAssetPath, pTextureX, pTextureY, pTileColumns, pTileRows);

Your code will change as below

```
mSapoTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mActivity.getTextureManager(),256,256,TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
mPlayerDownITiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mPlayerTextureAtlas, mActivity.getAssets(), "player.png", 0,0,3,4);
```

To animate player in different directions use this technique
define an array as

```
long[] ANIMATE_DURATION = new long[] { 200, 200, 200 };

AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(x, y, this.mPlayerTextureRegion,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());



// Down
player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 0, 2, true);
// Up
player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 9, 11, true);
// Right
player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 6, 8, true);
// Left
player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 3, 5, true);
```

look this [Example](https://github.com/jaymzcd/andengine_stripped/blob/master/src/org/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java) for more information.

If you have doubt ask me. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your response, Harry. I have edit my code follow your description, but nothing changes. I will take a deeper look.

Comment: See edited answer, you need to load texture with number of rows and column in player sprite.

Comment: Thank you so much, Harry. The problem is solved now. I must load entire the atlas rather than just load a row.

Answer (score 0):

First: Atlas should be in power of two so change it size to 256x256.
Second:

```
  mPlayerDownITiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mPlayerTextureAtlas, mActivity.getAssets(), "player.png", 0,0,3,1);
```

Last two digits say how many rows and columns you have. You declared 3 columns and 1 row.

Three: Zindex at 100 is needed only if you have so many layers. If not you dont need it.